# Crashlytics doesn't work with C++ crash on Android 6.0 or higher

Tags: java, android, c++, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have a problem when implement Crashlytics in my game. It can send Java crash reports on device has fw >= 6.0 but not C++ crash. Here are some logs when relaunch after C++ crash:

```
12-25 09:59:09.222: D/libcrashlytics(3881): Initializing libcrashlytics version 1.1.3
12-25 09:59:09.222: D/libcrashlytics(3881): Attempting to load unwinder...
12-25 09:59:09.230: E/libcrashlytics(3881): Failed to find any usable unwinding libraries on the device, falling back to simple unwinding
12-25 09:59:09.230: D/libcrashlytics(3881): Done; using simple
12-25 09:59:09.230: D/libcrashlytics(3881): Attempting to register signal handler...
12-25 09:59:09.230: D/libcrashlytics(3881): Signal handler registered.
12-25 09:59:09.230: D/libcrashlytics(3881): Initializing native crash handling successful.
12-25 09:59:09.236: I/CrashlyticsCore(3881): Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.10.127
12-25 09:59:10.779: W/cr_CrashFileManager(3881): /data/user/0/com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftDYHM/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
12-25 09:59:10.995: E/CrashlyticsNdk(3881): Crashlytics failed to parse prior crash data.
```

Btw, it works well both C++ and Java crash on Android fw <= 5.
Does anyone have ideas to fix it? I don't know where to start.